# I am usig spring boot to convert JSON ito java oject however when i run it it throws a file not found error

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am trying to convert a json file into a java object however by reading a json file.however when i run the spring boot application it throws a file not found exceptio while the file exists in the source/main/java/example/com path.

How do i resolve the error.
please find my codes here: i have two classes address and customer and a main

`Address class`

```
public class Address {   
private String street;
private String city;
private int zipcode;
private String country;

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public int getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
}

public void setZipcode(int zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{" +
            "street='" + street + '\'' +
            ", city='" + city + '\'' +
            ", zipcode=" + zipcode +
            ", country='" + country + '\'' +
            '}';
}

}
```

Customer class

```
 public class Customer {
 private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private int age;
    private String[] projects;
    private Address address;
    private List<String> paymentMethods;
    private Map<String, Object> profileInfo;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String[] getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(String[] projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public List<String> getPaymentMethods() {
        return paymentMethods;
    }

    public void setPaymentMethods(List<String> paymentMethods) {
        this.paymentMethods = paymentMethods;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getProfileInfo() {
        return profileInfo;
    }

    public void setProfileInfo(Map<String, Object> profileInfo) {
        this.profileInfo = profileInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", projects=" + Arrays.toString(projects) +
                ", address=" + address +
                ", paymentMethods=" + paymentMethods +
                ", profileInfo=" + profileInfo +
                '}';
    }


   }
```

Demo1Application.java

```
package com.example.demo;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication


public class Demo1Application implements CommandLineRunner  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);

}

 @Override
    public void run(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //create ObjectMapper instance
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //read json file and convert to customer object
        Customer customer = objectMapper.readValue(new File("‪‪F:\\programs\\demo-1\\src\\main\\java\\com\\example\\demo\\json_file"), Customer.class);

        //print customer details
        System.out.println(customer);
    }

}
```

here is the error:

Failed to execute CommandLineRunner

at com.example.demo.Demo1Application.main(Demo1Application.java:17) [classes/:na]

**Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ‪‪F:\programs\demo-1\src\main\java\com\example\demo\json_file (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)**

can someone help me resolve this

Comment: `while the file exists in the source/main/java/example/com path`, but you are reading from `\\com\\example\\demo\\`

Comment: The exception could not be clearer. The file ‪‪F:\programs\demo-1\src\main\java\com\example\demo\json_file does not exists

Comment: im aware of what the exception say however it exists right in the path where it is said it doesnt exist

Comment: @lebecca i havent written the path fully however it exists in the path